# How can I install OpenCV for python on mac?

Tags: macos, opencv, python-3.x, python-3.5

i'm trying to install opencv for python35 on el capitan. so far i've only been able to find tutorials that use homebrew, and i find them very confusing. i've managed to set up opencv on my windows machine by installing it via a .whl file. i haven't had much luck with my mac though, i'm not sure how i'd link homebrew to my python35 installation.
which python3 leads me to here /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3

Comment: Is there something specific you find confusing? The summary is, you install the OS X development tools, you install CMake and you run cmake, and then make and make install. Need to make sure you activate Python support and that it links to the python you want (namely 3.5). Without saying what you find difficult, it is hard to help you and this question is at great risk for being closed.

Comment: hi, ive edited my question slightly

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something I'm missing from your question. Installing OpenCV should be trivial:

```
unzip opencv-3.0.0.zip
cd opencv-3.0.0/
mkdir build
cd build
ccmake ../
```

- press c to configure
- edit the compile options you want, focus on which python 3.5 to use, point things to the correct directory
- when happy with the options press g to generate
- press q to quit

then you finish by:

```
make    
make install
```

Comment: im using the gui version, which generator should i use?

Comment: got this error: Make Error at cmake_install.cmake:31 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file
  "/Users/Raihaan/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_osx/lib/libippicv.a"
  to "/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/libippicv.a".

Comment: Try to configure things so the installation location is in /Users/Raihaan/local/ (create the directory first) instead of /usr/local/, it seems that you do not have a lot of experience with this type of thing, so I would not advice invoking root access to install things into /usr/local/ that you wouldn't know how to later remove/modify.

Comment: i think i should give up until i have more experience. for now i will just use my windows pc, but thank you for your time

Comment: @R21 You can execute `sudo make install` instead of `make install`, of course you must understand what are you doing.

Comment: @acgtyrant i've decided to just stick to my windows machine (unnoficial python binaries are very convenient), a lot simpler for a command line noob. Thanks for your input though